How to have a programmatical conversation with an agent created by Agent Builder
I created an agent with No Code tools offered by the Agent Builder GUI: https://vertexaiconversation.cloud.google.com/
I created a playbook and added a few Data store Tools for the agent to use for RAG.
I'd like to call this agent programmatically to integrate it into mobile apps or web pages. There's a lot of code related to the classic Dialogflow agents, the Agent Builder is quite new and uses the Gemini 1.0 Pro under the hood.
I've seen this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/78229704/292502 however the question was about DialogFlow ES while the Agent Builder agent is rather a DialogFLow CX agent under the hood (and is listed in the Dialogflow CX dashboard). The Python package is promising, but I haven't found how can I have a conversation with the agent Playbook after I get hold of one.
Or maybe I'm just looking at the wrong place. I was also browsing https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/main/dialogflow-cx but webhooks, intents and fulfillments are for the "classic" agents. I tried to go over https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/main/packages/google-cloud-dialogflow-cx/samples/generated_samples/ but haven't find the one which would help me yet.

Looks like the "traditional" Dialogflow CX API calls can invoke an Agent Builder agent:
import uuid
from google.cloud.dialogflowcx_v3beta1.services.agents import AgentsClient
from google.cloud.dialogflowcx_v3beta1.services.sessions import SessionsClient
from google.cloud.dialogflowcx_v3beta1.types import session

PROJECT_ID = "your-project-name"
LOCATION_ID = "project-region"  # example: us-central1
AGENT_ID = "a uuid of the agent"
AGENT = f"projects/{PROJECT_ID}/locations/{LOCATION_ID}/agents/{AGENT_ID}"
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

SESSION_ID = uuid.uuid4()
session_path = f"{AGENT}/sessions/{SESSION_ID}"
print(f"Session path: {session_path}\n")
client_options = None
agent_components = AgentsClient.parse_agent_path(AGENT)
location_id = agent_components["location"]
if location_id != "global":
    api_endpoint = f"{LOCATION_ID}-dialogflow.googleapis.com:443"
    print(f"API Endpoint: {api_endpoint}\n")
    client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}

session_client = SessionsClient(client_options=client_options)

text = "Your test prompt"
text_input = session.TextInput(text=text)
query_input = session.QueryInput(text=text_input, language_code=LANGUAGE_CODE)
request = session.DetectIntentRequest(
    session=session_path, query_input=query_input
)
response = session_client.detect_intent(request=request)

print("=" * 20)
print(f"Query text: {response.query_result.text}")
response_messages = [
    " ".join(msg.text.text) for msg in response.query_result.response_messages
]
print(f"Response text: {' '.join(response_messages)}\n")


Is it possible to call a specific agent using this dialogflow CX SDK ?

@Someone The AGENT_ID identifies the exact agent. You can see that if you list all apps in the Agent Builder, or the apps actually pop up on the DialogFlow CX UI as well. The agent builder has a concept of multiple playbooks (each playbook could kinda mean an agent scenario), but I don't think it's possible to specify playbook within an agent app.

First understand your business requirements which dialogflow service you want to use

If you have requirement like intent like conversation then use custom flow
If you have requirement like FAQS then use Data Store (Search and Conversation or Vertex AI app builder )
Playbook is for use generative AI as a prompt

And about integration you can use Dialogflow API or custom integration for this
Reference :- https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration
